# Mysql correct compare dates

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In my db I have table 'leads' with column 'datum_event' (varchar). I need get rows between 'from' to 'to' datum_event. For example, from 30.11.2018 to 31.03.2019. I use str_to_date for convert varchar to date for compare.

My sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(l.lead_id)
FROM leads as l
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(datum_event,'%d.%m.%y') >= STR_TO_DATE('30.11.2018','%d.%m.%y')
  AND STR_TO_DATE(datum_event,'%d.%m.%y') <= STR_TO_DATE('31.03.2019','%d.%m.%y')
ORDER BY  l.lead_id  desc
```

But now i get empty result. It is wrong. There is row with datum_event '01.12.2018', but I can't see it in result.

I can see result if compare dates are in one year, for example, from 01.01.2019 to 31.03.2019, but if i compare from 31.12.2018 I can't see any result.

Please help me, how can i solve this? Thanks.

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT`! Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `SELECT DISTINCT l.lead_id FROM 

leads ...` to make code clearer!

Comment: Understood. But it doesnt solve my problem

Comment: Also need get data, for example only from '31.12.2018' or only to '31.03.2019'

Comment: Use proper data types. Never store dates etc in character columns.

Comment: Try `SELECT l.lead_id, STR_TO_DATE(datum_event,'%d.%m.%y'), STR_TO_DATE('30.11.2018','%d.%m.%y') from leads as l`. Do you get a result that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use SQL `BETWEEN` condition.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(l.lead_id)
FROM leads as l
WHERE (STR_TO_DATE(datum_event,'%d.%m.%y') BETWEEN 
STR_TO_DATE('30.11.2018','%d.%m.%y') AND STR_TO_DATE('31.03.2019','%d.%m.%y'))
ORDER BY  l.lead_id  desc`
```

Answer (score 0):

`select STR_TO_DATE('30.11.2018','%d.%m.%y')` it will return 2020-11-30
but your need `2018-11-30` this date so you have to change like below
in format

```
  select STR_TO_DATE('30.11.2018','%d.%m.%Y') this will `2018-11-30`
```

i have added date format as demo[link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e2c71e0afdee6d620f0152287b16e351)

so in your query you need to correct your format

```
SELECT l.lead_id
FROM leads as l
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(datum_event,'%d.%m.%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE('30.11.2018','%d.%m.%Y')
  AND STR_TO_DATE(datum_event,'%d.%m.%Y') <= STR_TO_DATE('31.03.2019','%d.%m.%Y')
ORDER BY  l.lead_id  desc
```

Comment: @Ingus >= and <= is worked as like between so there is no trick here

Comment: @Ingus that is different issue